# Automating Glassfish Server during Apache Netbeans installation

Tags: installation, netbeans, glassfish

I've used the *Apache-NetBeans-20r1-bin-windows-x64.exe --record* to create an xml to pre-configure settings like the Microsoft OpenJDK 21 Java Path - however I can't seem to find any information on pre-install a Glassfish 7.0.9 server during installation.

I tried adding a property to the Install.xml, out of desperation really, but does someone have a way of deploying NetBeans and having it auto-add an Eclipse Glassfish7 server? Even if it's as simple as creating it manually then copying the server details from a directory on one PC to another?

`<product platform="windows linux" status="to-be-installed" uid="glassfish-mod" version="7.0.9"> <properties> <property name="installation.location">$N{install}/glassfish7</property> <property name="installation.location.windows">C:\Program Files\glassfish7</property> </properties> </product>`